# Security of xhost (local) and sudo xauthority forwarding

Tags: x11, security, xorg, sudo, xhost

Context: launch a GUI application as a linux service. I considered making a headless daemon with a GUI front-end but there is too much code involved to do it now. This service must start on user login, it should be started in the user shell (file rights are important here). No interaction of root should be necessary (auto-install from a RPM). Plus the system (root) must be able to start and stop this service to perform maintenance tasks called by cron.

I manage to do it so far, but I have security question about it : does the following break some X server security once the user 'username' in logged ?

1. .xinitrc created in '/home/username', calling xhost before starting the windows manager

   ```
   xhost + local:username
   exec $WINDOWMANAGER
   ```
2. '/etc/sudoers' modified with a custom editor to add those lines

   ```
   username localhost = NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/my-daemon
   Defaults env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORITY"
   ```
3. service script '/etc/init.d/my-daemon'

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   DISPLAY=${DISPLAY:-:0.0}
   export DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
   gnomesu -u username -c 'my-gui-app-bin with-some-arguments'
   ```
4. my-daemon service don't start on any level (DISPLAY not ready even on level 5)

   ```
   chkconfig --del my-daemon
   ```
5. autostart of the deamon via a .desktop file in '/etc/xdg/autostart/' and the following script

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   sudo /etc/init.d/my-daemon start
   ```